# Wpf Databinding with ViewModel as property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

to keep my MainWindow.xaml.cs clean I tried to outsource everything to a ViewModel class and then bind my view to properties of my ViewModel property
However using this extra layer doesn't seem to work. My List- and Textbox just stay empty. Any way to get this method working?

MainWindow class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_oneLineOnly;

    private ObservableCollection<string> m_sampleLines;

    public ObservableCollection<string> SampleLines
    {
        get => m_sampleLines;
        set
        {
            m_sampleLines = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SampleLines));
        }
    }

    public string OneLineOnly
    {
        get => m_oneLineOnly;

        set
        {
            m_oneLineOnly = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(OneLineOnly));
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        SampleLines = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string>()
        {
            "Gedanken",
            "Zeit",
            "Sand"
        });

        OneLineOnly = "Hello World";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handlers = PropertyChanged;

        handlers(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

MainWindow XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DataContext_Test_Project.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataContext_Test_Project"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    x:Name="Window">
<Grid>
    <ListBox 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="100"
        Margin="334,132,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="100"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ViewModel.SampleLines}"/>
    <TextBox
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="23"
        Margin="184,166,0,0" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="120"
        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ViewModel}"
        Text="{Binding Path=OneLineOnly}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does your Output window show binding errors? Try to use this method to add more information about the bindings and see where they resolve to: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/12/11/wpf-data-binding-debug/

Comment: Just call `ViewModel = new ViewModel();` before `InitializeComponent();` and everything works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also define the DataContext in code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
}
```

And clean your XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="100"
         Margin="334,132,0,0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="100"
         ItemsSource="{Binding SampleLines}"/>
    <TextBox
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Height="23"
         Margin="184,166,0,0" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="120"
         Text="{Binding OneLineOnly}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is it still possible to assign a different datacontext for individual textboxes with this solution?

Comment: Yes. Defining DataContext on children `Controls` (whatever their level) will override the global one.

Comment: I like to do this in XAML so that I get Intelisense: (in Window tag) `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel}"`

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek If you just want that for intellisense, you can use the "designer" bindings so that it doesn't apply at run-time. `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyViewModelType}"`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make Bindings like

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ViewModel.SampleLines}"
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ViewModel}"
```

work, you have two options. Either make the `ViewModel` property fire a property change notification, or simply initialize it before the XAML is parsed, i.e. before `InitializeComponent()` is called:

Like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {     
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Or simpler:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {     
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from xaml.cs file : ViewModel = new ViewModel();
Use the following code for Xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="DataContext_Test_Project.MainWindow"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataContext_Test_Project"
                    mc:Ignorable="d"
                    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
                    x:Name="Window" DataContext="{DynamicResource ViewModel}">
     <Window.Resources>
            <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
            </Window.Resources>
                <Grid>
                    <ListBox 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Height="100"
                        Margin="334,132,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Width="100"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SampleLines}"/>
                    <TextBox
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Height="23"
                        Margin="184,166,0,0" 
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Width="120"
                        Text="{Binding Path=OneLineOnly}"/>
                </Grid>
        </Window>
```

Comment: This would work. But is it possible to keep the object creation in code behind?

Comment: Yes you can keep view model object in code behind and set the data context there. But it is not advisable if you are using MVVM pattern.
Also keep in mind to define data context either in xaml file or code behind